# Q# How to use a namespace in another project?

Tags: programming, q#

I have some utility operations that I'd like to use across projects. How can I import its namespace using Q# in Visual Studio 2017 in other projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to add the project which contains the utility operations as a reference to the project which will be using them. If you're using Visual Studio Code or command line, you can use [dotnet add reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference) command to do that, and in Visual Studio you can use [Reference Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager).

Second, you need to open the namespace which contains the utility operations in each Q# file which uses them. To do this, add an `open` statement after the declaration of the namespace and before definition of any functions or operations:

```
namespace ProjectNamespace {
    open Utilities;

    // you can use operations defined in Utilities namespace now
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, worked like a charm! Now that Q# 0.3 is out, I'd like to update my Utilities project with the new code, but allow some of my other projects to use the old version. I see the quantum development kit's version can be referenced like so `    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Quantum.Development.Kit" Version="0.3.1810.2508-preview" />`. I'm having trouble finding documentation on how I can do this with my custom namespace. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: QDK can be referenced by version because it's packaged as a NuGet package. I don't think you can do this if you're using references between projects in one solution. One thing you can do is package your old Utilities project as a NuGet package (locally, without pushing it to nuget.org) and use a reference to it instead of a direct project reference when you need a 0.2 version.